# SSL Certificate from pem and key files

Tags: ssl, openssl, tls1.2

I have requested a wildcard SSL certificate from 123-reg and been provided a .pem which contains Begin and end certificate request. I have also been provided a .key with a begin and end rsa private key and a file containing the original password. I need a .pfx file to install in Azure. How do I get this?

I've tried:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey private-key.key -in XXXXXX_csr.pem -name "my name" -out toimport.pfx -passin file:private-key.password
```

but I get the message "No certificate matches private key"

Comment: Your `-in` value should be a PEM formatted public certificate that you obtained from 123-reg, not the certificate request.

Comment: Hi, that was all that was included in the files they sent. Am I doing it wrong or is what they have sent missing something?

Comment: You should have received a certificate file that starts with `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` and ends with `-----END CERTIFICATE-----`. This is your public certificate. The certificate request is something that you would have sent to them.